# Change folder where exported files are saved

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, export, inkscape

What I use:

- Mountain Lion 10.8.3
- Inkscape 0.48
- 3 files for Inkscape exension to export TikZ code (tikz_export.py, tikz_export_effect.inx, tikz_export_output.inx) (A bug has been dealt with following https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/194132)

What I got:

- Exported files are saved in a folder (HOME/.config/inkscape/extensions/) where those three files for TikZ export extension are located.

What I want to know

- ways to change/specify a folder where exported files are saved.

Can anyone help?